# how to fill order arguments in multilabel in R - MLR package

Tags: multilabel-classification, mlr

**I want to change the order in Classifier Chains multilabel classification**

makeMultilabelClassifierChainsWrapper(learner, order = NULL)

how to fill order arguments ? except NULL

Comment: Have you seen [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mlr/versions/2.19.0/topics/makeMultilabelClassifierChainsWrapper)? You can specify the order explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. But I still don't get it how to fill, can you give me example? thank you in advance @LarsKotthoff

Comment: E.g. `order = c("label1", "label2", "label3")`.